# Peoplepickerdidselectperson keeps dismissing after person is selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, abpeoplepickerview

For my app, I am trying to detect whether or not a selected person's contact consists of more than 1 phone number. If it only contains 1 number, I want to use

```
    -(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

         [self peoplePickerNavigationController:peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:person];
            }

    -(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
return YES;
}
```

and get the phone number. However, if it contains more than one, I want to use

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
}
```

so that the user can select which phone number to use. However, whenever using the

```
-(void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

}
```

after selecting a person, it will always dismiss the view by itself. I tried adding

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

into the first method but that didn't seem to work either and the view still dismissed itself. How can I prevent the view from dismissing itself or is there another method I should be using?

Best

Comment: Did you implement the various `shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson` delegate methods? Show more of your code.

Comment: yes, i tried adding '-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person' and added 
    [self peoplePickerNavigationController:peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:person];

Comment: Please update your question with relevant code. Don't put it in the comments.